# React: How to reuse components with their own dataset?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Trying to do a dropzone upload component that allows user to tag each image uploaded using an input field..

Problem is the tags used for the first image is also loaded in the tag for the second image...

Ideally, each image should have its own "set" of tags on upload. Not sure what am I missing in terms of reusing the TagInput component.

Screenshot below to show the erroneous behavior:

[image]

**Dropzone.js**

```
  const [tags, setTags] = useState({});

  const addTagHandler = (aTag, index) => {
    let result;
    if (Object.keys(tags).length === 0) {
      // if nothing, create.
      result = { [index]: [aTag] };
    } else {
      //check index, if index exists, push to index. else, create index
      if (index < Object.keys(tags).length) {
        result = { ...tags, [index]: [...tags[index], aTag] };
      } else {
        result = { ...tags, [index]: [aTag] };
      }
    }
    setTags(result);
  };

  <div className="file-display-container">
    {validFiles.map((aFile, index) => (
      <div className="file-status-bar" key={index}>
        <div>
          {previewUrl && (
            <div className="file-preview">
              <img src={previewUrl[index]} alt="image" />
            </div>
          )}
          <span
            className={`file-name ${aFile.invalid ? "file-error" : ""}`}
          >
            {aFile.name}
          </span>
          <span className="file-size">({fileSize(aFile.size)})</span>{" "}
          {aFile.invalid && (
            <span className="file-error-message">({errorMessage})</span>
          )}
        </div>

        <TagInput
          tags={tags[index]}
          onAdd={(aTag) => addTagHandler(aTag, index)}
          onDelete={deleteTagHandler}
        />
        <div
          className="file-remove"
          onClick={() => removeFile(aFile.name)}
        >
          X
        </div>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
```

TagInput.js

```
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  const _keyPressHandler = (event) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter" && input.trim() !== "") {
      onAdd(input.trim());
      setInput("");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="taginput">
      {tags &&
        tags.map((aTag, index) => (
          <Tag
            key={aTag + index}
            label={aTag}
            onClickDelete={() => onDelete(index)}
          />
        ))}

      <Input
        type="text"
        value={input}
        onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
        onKeyPress={_keyPressHandler}
        placeholder="Insert tag here"
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: it would be a lot nicer if you could only send the relevant parts of the code so we could focus on the core issue

Comment: @lanxion yup, updated the post with the solution I used with reference to you and Todd's answer. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the same array of tags to each `TagInput` component. They need to be separated in some fashion.

What you need to do is create a tag array for each input. You could do this by using an object based on the file key.

Something like this should work. Just pass the key of the file to each handler so it updates the appropriate array.

```
const [tags, setTags] = useState({});

const addTagHandler = (key, tag) => {
  setTags({...tags, [key]: [...tags[key], tag]});
};

const deleteTagHandler = (key, i) => {
  setTags({...tags, [key]: tags[key].filter((_, index) => index !== i));
};
```

Update your tag component to use the key `i` like so.

```
<TagInput
  tags={tags[i]}
  onAdd={tag => addTagHandler(i,tag)}
  onDelete={tagIndex => deleteTagHandler(i,tagIndex)}
/>
```

Comment: Yup. Got it. I added some more logic to suit my case. Answer updated in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in how you are setting the `tags` state. In your line `const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);`, you are setting tags as a single array of strings, which is being used by every consequent image with a tag, as seen in the line

```
              <TagInput
                tags={tags}
                onAdd={addTagHandler}
                onDelete={deleteTagHandler}
              />
```

where you are reusing the same `tags` state among all the divs in `.file-display-container`.

A solution for this would be to instead have an array of strings **inside the state array**. (`tags: [["tag1", "tag2"], ["image2Tag1"], ....]`)

so in your old line where you set `tags={tags}` for each `TagInoput`, you would instead set is as `tags={tags[i]}`(the index is i in your map function).

you would need to adjust the tag handler functions accordingly. (@Todd Skelton's answer provides a fantastic way to handle it)

Comment: Yup. Got it. I added some more logic to suit my case. Answer updated in my post.